# Hiding first TabPanel of TabContainer hides the TabContainer

Tags: asp.net

I have an ajax tab container with 3 tabs.the problem is that when I make the first tab invisible,it makes the entire tab container invisible.
i have something like

```
<tk:TabContainer ID="TabContainer1" runat="server"   >

     <tk:TabPanel ID="Tabpanell" runat="server" >
</tk:TabPanel>
<tk:TabPanel ID="Tabpanel2" runat="server" >
</tk:TabPanel>
<tk:TabPanel ID="Tabpanel3" runat="server" >
</tk:TabPanel>
</tk:TabContainer>
```

and in code behind,on page load i need to show only some tabpanels based on condition that is..

```
 protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!IsPostBack)
        {
          if (!CheckViewPermissionTab1())
           {
             Tabpanel1.visible=false;
           }
        }
    }
```

but when i try to set the first tabpanel's visibilit to false ,the entire tab container gets hidden.There is no problem whwn the second or third panel's visibility is set to false.

Comment: Can you share your code(what you've tried) here?

Comment: Thank you so much for your attention.I have added some more information regarding my issue.please have a look at it.

Comment: Did you tried the following code `TabContainer1.Tabs[0].visible=false;`

Comment: yes I tried..but it resulted in the same problem..the entire Tabcontainer is invisible when I do this.

Comment: Okay did you tried with css? `.hidetab { display:none }`. then `Tabpanel1.cssClass="hidetab" ;` or `TabContainer1.Tabs[0].cssClass="hidetab";`

Comment: :( still not working.

Comment: I think this is a bug in AjaxControlToolkit. Which version of ACTK you are using?

Comment: may be..am using Version 3.5.40412.2

Comment: [This link](http://blog.bennedik.de/2009/02/how-to-hide-tabpanels-of-aspnet-ajax.html) may help you...

Comment: try the code in chat window http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/102888/discussion-between-sruthi-suresh-and-sankar-raj

Comment: oh god..it worked...thank you sooo much..

Comment: The problem is tabcontainer need atleast a tab should be active otherwise it will go invisible so if you set a tab to visible=false, then you have to set any other tab to be active.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is tabcontainer need atleast a tab should be active otherwise it will go invisible so if you set a tab to `visible=false`, then you have to set any other tab to be active.

```
 protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e) 
 { 
    if (!IsPostBack) 
    { 
        if (!CheckViewPermissionTab1()) 
        { 
            Tabpanel1.visible=false; 
            TabContainer1.ActiveTab = Tabpanel2; 
        } 
     } 
 }
```

Try the above code.